# Measuring the duration of NaN gaps in columns of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas DataFrame with an irregular sampling pattern that has gaps in each column. To provide a concrete example:

```
tndx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-04 00:00','2019-01-04 03:00',
                         '2019-01-04 10:17','2019-01-04 19:00',
                         '2019-01-05 09:00','2019-01-06 10:00',
                         '2019-01-07 16:00','2019-01-09 14:50'])

data = {"op":['a','a','b','b','b',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 
        "setting":[1.,2.,1.,np.nan,np.nan,2.,1.,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,index = tndx)


                      op  setting 
2019-01-04 00:00:00    a      1.0 
2019-01-04 03:00:00    a      2.0 
2019-01-04 10:17:00    b      1.0
2019-01-04 19:00:00    b      NaN 
2019-01-05 09:00:00    b      NaN
2019-01-06 10:00:00  NaN      2.0 
2019-01-07 16:00:00  NaN      1.0
2019-01-09 14:50:00  NaN      NaN
```

I would like to create a DataFrame of the same dimensions with each entry representing the duration of the current NaN/non-NaN state.  So that output using minutes would be:

```
                      op  setting
2019-01-04 00:00:00 3480     1140
2019-01-04 03:00:00 3480     1140
2019-01-04 10:17:00 3480     1140
2019-01-04 19:00:00 3480     2340
2019-01-05 09:00:00 3480     2340
2019-01-06 10:00:00 4610     4610
2019-01-07 16:00:00 4610     4610
2019-01-09 14:50:00 4610      0
```

The datatype of the result doesn't matter -- seconds/minutes/timedelta. Boundary cases at the end also are not too important. What is the best way to do do this?

Comment: Sure. That is the length in minutes the period stayed "not missing" between the beginning of the series. Think of "op'" as being either in the NaN or non-NaN state.

Comment: Very close. I was assuming the state ends 2019-01-04 19:00:00. I see the economy in your solution here though.

Comment: Answer was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution get difference of firt and next first consecutive missing and non missing values for each column:

```
s = df.index.to_series()
cols = ['op','setting']
for c in cols:
    #test missing values
    miss = df[c].isna()
    #create consecutive groups
    g = miss.ne(miss.shift()).cumsum()
    #aggregate minimal 
    m1 = s.groupby(g).min()
    #get minimal of next groups, last valueis replaced last value of index
    m2 = m1.shift(-1).fillna(df.index[-1])
    #get difference, convert to minutes
    out = m2.sub(m1).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
    #map to column
    df[c] = g.map(out)
print (df)

                       op  setting
2019-01-04 00:00:00  3480     1140
2019-01-04 03:00:00  3480     1140
2019-01-04 10:17:00  3480     1140
2019-01-04 19:00:00  3480     2340
2019-01-05 09:00:00  3480     2340
2019-01-06 10:00:00  4610     4610
2019-01-07 16:00:00  4610     4610
2019-01-09 14:50:00  4610        0
```